MSAGL: WpfGraphControl: Can two nodes placed next to each other after graph generation?
Can two nodes in WpfGraphControl be located next to each other after graph generation?
Something like this:
I`m trying to use Attr.length property, but it has no effect.
Also assign zero to Attr. Separation will not give significant effect. It's just a short line.
